# Map merge-function (shouldn't be called!?)

Tags: java

I don't get in this rather short method posted below why the `merger()` function is called (to determine what happens with values which are associated with the same key).

The method is supposed to group the list of search configurations by their application and sort the map keys (the applications by their names), as well as the map values (the search configurations by their names). Maybe the second stream isn't straight forward and I could/should use another approach, but nontheless I want to understand what's happening.

Output is something along the lines:

- App1

  - Search Config Title1
  - Search Config Title2
- App2

  - Search Config Title
- App3

  - Search Config Title1
  - Search Config Title2
  - Search Config Title3

The ApplicationInfo implementation isn't overriding `int hashCode()` nor `boolean equals(Object)`.

I would have thought that the map keys are always different in the second stream for each list of search configurations. However, in one particular situation the merge-function is called which I don't get why at all it's called.

```
public SortedMap<ApplicationInfo, List<SearchConfigInfo>> groupByApplications(final BusinessLogicProcessingContext  ctx,
                                                                              final List<SearchConfigInfo>          searchConfigInfos) {
  requireNonNull(ctx, "The processing context must not be null.");
  requireNonNull(searchConfigInfos, "The search configuration informations must not be null.");

  final String                    lang;
  final RtInfoWithTitleComparator comp;

  lang = ContextLanguage.get(ctx);
  appComp = new RtInfoWithTitleComparator(lang);

  final Map<ApplicationInfo, List<SearchConfigInfo>> appToSearchConfigs;

  appToSearchConfigs = searchConfigInfos.stream()
                                        .collect(groupingBy(searchConfig -> RtCache.getApplication(searchConfig.getApplicationGuid())));

  return appToSearchConfigs.entrySet()
                           .stream()
                           .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                          p_entry -> _sortValueList(p_entry.getValue()),
                                          merger(),
                                          () -> new TreeMap<>(appComp)));
}
```

The general contract of a map is:

"An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value."

That's why I really wonder what happens in this case.

```
private static BinaryOperator<List<SearchConfigInfo>> merger() {
  return (list1, list2) -> { System.out.println(RtCache.getApplication(list1.get(0).getApplicationGuid()).hashCode());
        System.out.println(RtCache.getApplication(list2.get(0).getApplicationGuid()).hashCode());

         System.out.println(list1.get(0).getApplicationGuid().equals(list2.get(0).getApplicationGuid()));
    list1.addAll(list2);

    return list1;
  };
}
```

As I can see with the simple STDOUT debugging statements the hashCodes are different as well as they are not equal to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you're supplying a `TreeMap` as the result of the supplier function given to the `Collectors.toMap()` method (that's the last argument):

```
toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
       p_entry -> _sortValueList(p_entry.getValue()),
       merger(),
       () -> new TreeMap<>(appComp)));
```

(A supplier function provides the collection that the collector will use to contain the results - so in this case it always supplies a `TreeMap`.)

[A `TreeMap` performs key comparisons with `compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), which is why you can get a key collision in this case - the collisions are taken in respect to the *supplier* map, not the map from which they originate.